# Hibernate wildcard query on two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, search, query-builder, hibernate-search

I am trying to select persons from database by name and surname. User can type name or surname or both in one input box. E.g. if user type "Joh Smit" it should return John Smith, but user can also type just "Joh" or "Smi" to get this person

How should I build query to handle wildcards and all of words from user input?
My actual code looks like this:

```
String queryFilter = "";
for(String part : filter.split(" ")){
    queryFilter+=part.toLowerCase()+"* ";
}
queryFilter = queryFilter.trim();

query = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("firstname").andField("lastname").matching(queryFilter).createQuery();
```

This can not handle multiple words from user input, due the `.wildcard()`, but when I remove `.wildcard()` I will not be able to search not exact names.

Comment: You can do that by Hibernate Criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build a boolean query where one part targets the firstname and the other the lastname. Something like this:

Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
    .bool()
      .should(  )
      .should(  )
    .createQuery();

See also the Hibernate Search online docs - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl - in particular the "combining queries" section.